# Arcpy MakeFeatureLayer_management issue using SQL condition

Tags: arcpy, layers, error-000358

I have a lines shapefile. I made a small code to select some of its elements and turn them into a standalone layer. The code is like this:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\MyDirectory\Mygdb.gdb"
network = r"Linesshapefile"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(network,'Winners_lyr', "OBJECTID_12" in Winners)
arcpy.SavetoLayerFile_management('Winners_lyr','Winners_lyr')
```

The last line is because, according to the documentation, the layer is not saved but only locally created, since I want to be able to access it also after the code.

`Winners` is an list containing integer numbers, like this:

```
Winners = [1, 4, 59, 330]
```

`ObjectID_12`is the code that univocally identifies my elements ( I think it received the appendix `_12` because this code is the result of several geoprecessing actions, including intersections)

when I run my code, anyway, I get this error:

```
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6477, in MakeFeatureLayer
raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression 0
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).
```

I guess the issue is the SQL condition I wrote, but I am not sure how to fix it since the MakeFeatureLayer_management is not very generous of information concerning how to use this function.
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since `Winners` is a list of integers, and MakeFeatureLayer is expecting a SQL string in a particular format, you need to convert. Here's a simple way:

```
>>> Winners = [1, 4, 59, 330]
>>> sql = "OBJECTID_12 IN ({})".format(",".join(map(str, Winners)))
>>> print(sql)
'OBJECTID_12 IN (1,4,59,330)'
```

Since your values are integers, you need to cast to strings before joining with a comma.